Left Artinian ring where left and right socles are distinct
I'm trying to solve problem 4.20 from Lam's A First Course:
For any left artinian ring, $soc(_R R)=\{r\in R: Jr=0\}$ and $soc(R_R)=\{r\in R: rJ=0\}$ (where $J=J(R)$ is the Jacobson radical). Use this to construct a left artinian ring where $soc(_RR)\neq soc(R_R)$.
(recall the socle $soc(M)$ of a left/right $R$-module $M$ is the sum of the simple submodules of $M$)
I solved the first part of the problem (characterizing the socles), but I can't come up with an example of a left artinian ring with $soc(_RR)\neq soc(R_R)$.
I think generally I don't know many examples of rings that are/are not left/right Artinian/Noetherian (especially ones that aren't $J$-semisimple, which is pretty necessary for this question), so in addition to help with the question, common examples of rings that do/don't satisfy these conditions that I could toy with for future similar problems would be appreciated!
